Problem: Using Salesforce to connect to an AWS S3 using a secret key, access key and a Token requested from external api service
I am trying to fetch to an S3 from Salesforce, but in order to connect, I need to send User and Password a third party api and it will respond with the acces key, secret key and token.
How to implement this integration in Salesforce?
I think I should implement enviromental variables to save User and password in Salesforce, and then create an apex code to do all the requests. The problem is I do not know how to save them or if it is even posible. Any suggestions?
